# Значение слова днище

Tags: словообразование, лексикография, этимология

Из всех обсуждений я понял два значения этого слова - бесконечно длинный наполненный событиями день и часть   конструкции (корабля, лодки, бочки, большой емкости...). Я от старожил часто слышал, где днище было значением дня. В каких словарях посмотреть? В обсуждениях есть ссылка, но там не все словари.

Comment: Если хотите нашего мнения (Новая хронология), то ДНИЩЕ имеет отношение не к ДЕНЬ, к производимому ДНО. У него своя этимология, довольно широкая, с параллелями в латинском, греческом и современных западноевропейских языках, которые однако никак не отражены ни в словаре Фасмера, ни в других справочниках. Будет интересно, расскажу.
С Новым Годом!
Федор.

Comment: >Если хотите нашего мнения (Новая хронология)  
  
Если вы хотите нашего мнения, то "спасибо, не надо".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[[@Egor_855](/users/4608/egor_855)](/users/4608/egor_855), не знаю, какие-такие "старожилы", но "днище" в значении "длинный, тягучий день" в принципе возможно. Но это скорее как раз молодежный сленг, словарями не фиксируется.
Вот одно использование нашел (в самом низу) 
http://www.nevesta.info/forum/user233421/post/page19/

Про значение Людмилы (=расстояние, равное пути в один день) ни разу не слышал, не знаю. 
Единственное "словарное" упоминание - в вики - ссылается само на себя. Что, выражаясь тем же языком, "доставляет".
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%89%D0%B5

Answer (score 2):

В словарях это слово искать бесполезно. Днище - длинный день - это разговорное слово, может, и просторечие, в нормативных словарях его нет.

Но Ваш стАрожил, видимо, говорил об устаревшем слове ДНИЩЕ.

Оно употреблялось в Древней Руси в быту вместо старославянского заимствования ПОПРИЩЕ. Первоначально поприще должно было обозначать "место, которое топчут, по которому ходят".  В языке древнерусской письменности основным значением слова поприще является старославянская мера пути, стадий: мера пути длиной около 2/3 версты (греч. μíλιον); мера пути в полторы версты; мера пути в дневной переход (Срезневский, 2, с. 1203—1204).

( http://enc-dic.com/whistory/Poprische-699.html )

Вот последнее значение - мера пути в дневной переход - и называлось "днище" - расстояние, которое можно пройти за день.

Comment: Людмила, ну с поприщем понятно.
А **днище**-то каким образом могло тут использоваться?  Из текста по ссылке это совсем не следует.

Comment: Хотя в Интернете, говорят, можно всё найти, но, оказывается, не всё, ссылку предоставить не могу, хотя найти пыталась. Но слово встречалось, когда в институте переводили древнерусские тексты, запомнилось, потому что мы ещё смеялись, как изменились значения слов.Профессор рассказывала, что в живой речи старославянский редко использовался,и Щ там не было, произносилось вроде бы как " в дништех"или что-то наподобие, уже не помню, а потом стало "днище"(оно нам и встретилось, ни на что не похожее, а преподаватель сама перевела).

Comment: Людмила, я не понял выделения "А" в слове старожил? Старожил - старый житель какого-то места.

Comment: Про днище - продолжительный насыщенный день, так никто исчерпывающего ответа и не дал.

Comment: Вот именно, что стАрожил, а у Вас было стОрожил, проверьте версию до исправления.

Comment: А  почему  "от  старожил",  а  не  "от  старожилов"?  И  какого  места  эти  старожилы?  Просто  "старожилов"  не  бывает - старики, старые  люди.

Comment: Людмила, с Новым годом, версии первой у меня не было. Бернард, старожил, потому, что во множественном числе если вы правильно прочли мой вопрос.

Comment: Бернард, трудно понять иностранцу РУССКИЙ ЯЗЫК. Значение слова старожил
Новый толково-словообразовательный словарь русского языка. Автор Т. Ф. Ефремова.
старожил м. 1) Тот, кто долгое время живет в каком-л. месте. 2) перен. разг. Тот, кто в течение длительного времени работает, служит где-л.
Орфографический словарь
старожил старож`ил, -а
Толковый словарь под ред. C. И. Ожегова и Н.Ю.Шведовой
СТАРОЖИЛ, -а, м. Человек, к-рый много лет живет в каком-н. одном месте.Московский с. Старожилы не запомнят (о чем-н. редком, необычном, чегоникогда не бывало; разг.).

Answer (score 1):

Днище как день пути

Превращение временных понятий в пространственные, в измерительные единицы протяжения отражается в обычных для большинства языков выражениях: "два часа ходьбы до этой деревни", "три дня езды до города". Расстояние, которое можно было преодолеть за один день пути, в русском языке называлось "днище".

http://www.paganism.ru/astrorus.htm

Для древнерусского периода истории Руси характерны определения расстояний описательными выражениями – «вержение камня», «перестрел», «день пути». Средний размер перестрела выводится, как правило, из практики народов, пользующихся луком. Приблизительно он равен 60-70 м. Для «дня пути» условно применяется расстояние 25 (или 35-40) км, а для «конного дня пути» – 50-70 км.  Из подобных народно-бытовых мер расстояний можно назвать еще «днище» (от «день»), «стрелище», «метавище» (от «метать»).

http://bsk.nios.ru/content/metrologiya-drevney-i-srednevekovoy-rusi-x-xv-vv

Comment: Вера, спасибо за интересные, познавательные материалы.

Answer (score 0):

В современном молодежном слэнге употребляется и в значении, скажем так - абсолютно некомпетентный в чём-либо человек :)
Пример:
В астрономии ты днище
:)